# Can ant use the build.xml created by Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I exported a build.xml file from an Eclipse/Android project (under Windows). Then I use the command "ant release" to try to compile the project. But it always shows an error:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "release" does not exist in the project "xxxx".
```

So the question is: Can ant use the build.xml file created by Eclipse? Or, how can I resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the `android update project` command on your project to create a `build.xml` that is compatible with the Android build process. This will not disturb your existing Eclipse project files, so you will be able to build either way.

Comment: Thank you very much. Having updated the project, a new build.xml was created. With the new build.xml, the previous problem was resolved. Thank you! But when it compiles the code that was referencing to a third-party library (.jar), ant reports that "cannot find symbol." I think this must be some classpath problem, but isn't build.xml supposed to inherit everything from the Exlipse project? If it doesn't, can I modify the build.xml myself? How to add a classpath in build.xml? Thank you.

Comment: Your third-party JAR should be in your project's `libs/` directory for command-line builds.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! The JAR file was originally put in C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras, then I moved it to the projects libs folder and changed the classpath variable, then it worked. Thank you again!